# Plotting segments of a circle with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to split a circle into 11 equal pieces and plot them with ggplot2.

I am having a little trouble as my code is not producing even segments of the circles.

### code

```
## spilt the circle radians into 11 segments
angle_spilt <- (2*pi) / 11
angle_spilt_seq <- seq(0,(2*pi),angle_spilt)
angle_spilt_seq

## create a dataframe for plotting
distance.radius = 100
segment.line.dat <- data.frame(angle = angle_spilt_seq, stringsAsFactors = F)

# calculate new x,y based on angles - (origins at 0,0)
segment.line.dat$yend = distance.radius * sin(((segment.line.dat$angle * 180) / (pi)))
segment.line.dat$xend = distance.radius * cos(((segment.line.dat$angle * 180) / (pi)))
segment.line.dat$x = 0
segment.line.dat$y = 0

## plot the segments 
ggplot() + xlim(c(-110, 110)) + ylim(c(-110, 110)) + geom_segment(data = segment.line.dat, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend , yend = yend))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Comment: You are working in radians. You don't want 180; you want `pi`.

Comment: Thank MrFlick, do you know if there is a way to create one of these segments so they can be styled with both colour and fill?

Answer (score 3):

Solution is:

```
## spilt the circle radians into 11 segments
angle_spilt <- (2*pi) / 11
angle_spilt_seq <- seq(0,(2*pi),angle_spilt)
angle_spilt_seq

## create a dataframe for plotting
distance.radius = 100
segment.line.dat <- data.frame(angle = angle_spilt_seq, stringsAsFactors = F)

# calculate new x,y based on angles - (origins at 0,0)
segment.line.dat$yend = distance.radius * sin(((segment.line.dat$angle * pi) / (pi)))
segment.line.dat$xend = distance.radius * cos(((segment.line.dat$angle * pi) / (pi)))
segment.line.dat$x = 0
segment.line.dat$y = 0

## plot the segments 
ggplot() + xlim(c(-110, 110)) + ylim(c(-110, 110)) + geom_segment(data = segment.line.dat, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend , yend = yend))
```

[image]